# How can I ask for client confirmation to perform an action (like sending an email) on server side ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, email

I have a button that simply triggers a function that sends an email. I need the user's confirmation to send that email or cancel the process, here is my code:

- Button
  `<asp:Button ID="enviar" runat="server" Text="Envíar" OnClick = "enviar_Click"/>`
- enviar_Click() C# function on server side

  `protected void enviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`
- jquery function to return hidden values to fill the email

  ```
  elementosCompra = elementosCompra.filter(Boolean);

  $("#hiddenCompra").val(elementosCompra);
  $('#HiddenPuntos').val(hiddenPuntos);
  ```

Comment: You can use `$.AJAX({})` to call an event in code behind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javescript method:

```js
function requestConfirmation() {
  var answer = confirm('Do u want to continue ?');
  return answer;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="submit" onClick="return requestConfirmation();" />
</form>
```

Since you are using ASPX form, you have to change your aspx code as

```
<asp:Button ID="enviar" runat="server" Text="Envíar" OnClientClick = "return requestConfirmation();" OnClick = "enviar_Click"/>
<script>
    function requestConfirmation() {
      var answer = confirm('Do u want to continue ?');
      return answer;
    }
</script>
```

According to this the PostBack will happen only if the user confirms, using the javascript confirm dialog box. If the user hits cancel,then no submission happens.

Comment: First of all, thanks for that helpful response but, the problem remains in my application because the Onclick event steps over the function `requestConfirmation()` and does not trigger the `confirm()`

Comment: But always the client event will be triggered first. So requestConfirmation() will always be called first. OnClick will get triggered only after that. Please try to give an alert at the beginning of requestConfirmation, just before var 'answer = confirm'. If everything is right, it sould show alert box, before hitiing the server event.

Comment: Are you sure that you have written requestConfirmation() method under script tag on aspx page?

Comment: `<asp:Button ID="enviar" runat="server" Text="Enviar" OnClientClick="return requestConfirmation();" OnClick="enviar_Click"/>`

that's my actual code and i tried to put an alert at the beginning of requestConfirmation() just as you recommended to me: 

`alert("hello from client side");
        var answer = confirm('Do u want to continue?');
        return answer`

the application just steps over the entire function

Comment: Answering you second coment: i wrote it in my js file, must i include it in the aspx page directly?

Comment: No if the file is included in your page, its enough. But still you can give a try, moving it to the aspx page.

Comment: Yes!! I moved the script to the main page and it works! Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Ok, Still when get free time, it will be nice, if the issue when requestConfirmation() resides in external files is sorted. Sometimes you might have missed to refer the external file or some other unnoticed issues.

Answer (score 1):

Use Jquery.confirm.min.js Library

```
$.confirm({
 title: 'Confirm Message',
 text: 'Want to send?'
 confirm: function(){
  //your ajax call
},cancel:function(){
  return false;
},
confirmButton: "Yes",
cancelButton: "No"
});
```